# Java primitive-Object comparison: is the primitive autoboxed or the object unboxed?

Tags: java, autoboxing, unboxing

According to the [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) on autoboxing (and unboxing)

> Converting a primitive value (an int, for example) into an object of
>   the corresponding wrapper class (Integer) is called autoboxing. The
>   Java compiler applies autoboxing when a primitive value is:
>
> - Passed as a parameter to a method that expects an object of the
>     corresponding wrapper class.
> - Assigned to a variable of the
>     corresponding wrapper class.
>
> Converting an object of a wrapper type (Integer) to its corresponding
>   primitive (int) value is called unboxing. The Java compiler applies
>   unboxing when an object of a wrapper class is:
>
> - Passed as a parameter to a method that expects a value of the corresponding primitive type.
> - Assigned to a variable of the corresponding primitive type.

The tutorial further elaborates that operators like `%` and `+=` use `intValue` to convert an `Integer` to and `int` at runtime.

What actually happens when you do a comparison like `==`, `>`, or `<` on a primitive and a wrapper class?

For example, if I do `5 == Integer.valueOf(5)` is `5` autoboxed and evaluated as `Integer.valueOf == Integer.valueOf(5)` or is `Integer.valueOf(5)` unboxed and evaluated as `5 == 5`.

In this example, the functional result is equivalent since `Integer`s `-128` to `127` are cached, but how about for larger numbers?

Empirical tests running this on larger numbers suggests that the `Integer` object is unboxed and the comparison uses primitive values.  Is there official documentation that defines this behavior specifically?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2

Comment: I'm out of votes, but [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28022254/how-comparison-object-and-primitive-with-operator-works-in-java) would be an appropriate duplicate. And the same applies to all the operators that apply to numeric types.

Comment: I suspected it might be in the JLS, but it isn't that easily searchable.  Thanks!